# Qt Creator breaks on vsnprintf with normal strings on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, printf, clang

Sometimes when I deploy my debug c++/qt quick app to iOS (simulator) using QtCreator it breaks of certain statements, without any message about what's wrong

the case I'm after now is a call to vsnprintf where

- format is "tell user %s it failed with reason %s"
- and the arg list containing 'const char *'

char pointers are originating from

```
std::string thing; thing.c_str()
std::exception ex; ex.what()
```

It works on windows 32bit and it doesn't break/crash in release (also on iOS).

I would like to know:

1. Why does Qt Creator break? Can I somewhere see a description of what might be wrong? (I see no warning in the issues tab and nothing in application output)
2. If this is a kind of assert? can I somehow step over it? (continue does not seem to do anything)
3. Are there known issues with vsnprintf (in combination with clang/qt creator/iOS)?

the call stack at the time when it breaks:

```
strlen
__vfprintf
__v2printf
_vsnprintf
vsnprintf
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments, the code is under my control, somewhere deep down in a logging function

turns out that I wasn't using va_copy on the va_list and that using vsnprintf twice on the same va_list does not work on iOS (first time to determine the buffer size, second time to actually write the buffer)

So the remaining question is how/where can I configure QtCreator to show me an error message about what went wrong? instead of just break and let me guess that there might be something wrong

Comment: Is it your code that is using `vsnprintf`, or some internal code that is not under your control calling this function?  If it's the former, how are you verifying that it isn't a bug in your code that's causing the issue?

Comment: 1. do you use `-Wall` compiler switch? Many newbie mistakes are detected by compiler warnings. 2. show the code! Do not write about what is wrong in your opinion, since newbies are usually wrong about that. 3. Call stack of crashed thread should referrer to code we can see so it could be useful . 4. I'm sure there is some error information, but you do not know where to look for it.

Comment: Note iOS is 64 bit system. Some format string which are working on 32bit will fail on 64bit system usually `-Wall` detects such issues. Also modern C++ do not use `vsnprintf`!

Comment: A crash on `strlen` usually indicates that the pointer being given `strlen` is invalid.  You only showed that you're calling `c_str()`, but we have no context of where, when, or how that `std::string` object is used, whether it is still in scope, etc.  If that `std::string` is invalid, so is the `c_str()` that you're using from it.